# How to get the total right result in my report for entered calls?

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have report with entered calls.I want to get the total sum of my column `%Weekdays`.
For example i will show you my values and the expected result:
The expected result is 100,7%
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jKum.jpg

This is my code for %weekdays ( average values ) , but i want total values from all rows:

```
 =avg(IIF(Weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)<6,CDBL(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value),Nothing))/
iif(Sum(IIF(Weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)<6, CDBL(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value), Nothing),"PRESENTATION_NAME")=0,1   
    (Sum(IIF(Weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)<6, CDBL(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value), Nothing),"PRESENTATION_NAME")/
iif(code.getWeekDaysCount(Parameters!From_date.Value,Parameters!To_date.Value)=0,1,code.getWeekDaysCount(Parameters!From_date.Value, Parameters!To_date.Value))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to sum the "% weekdays" column, assuming it's called `myWeekdaysCol` then you can just do

```
=SUM(ReportItems!myWeekdaysCol.Value)
```

The will simply sum the final result without having to create a long, hard to read expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I simplified your data and have generated sum of it

%weekday is just `=Fields!Weekday.Value/10.40`

Then I just created outside Group-below for Sum of %weekday

[image]

[image]

and to generate sum it simply just

```
=Sum(Fields!Weekday.Value/10.40)
```

In my oversimplified case I generate &weekday with divide by 10.40 this is my formula.
You will have to do something like below

```
=Sum(avg(IIF(Weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)<6,CDBL(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value),Nothing))/
iif(Sum(IIF(Weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)<6, CDBL(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value), Nothing),"PRESENTATION_NAME")=0,1   
    (Sum(IIF(Weekday(Fields!DATE_YYYYMMDD.Value,2)<6, CDBL(Fields!N_ENTERED.Value), Nothing),"PRESENTATION_NAME")/
iif(code.getWeekDaysCount(Parameters!From_date.Value,Parameters!To_date.Value)=0,1,code.getWeekDaysCount(Parameters!From_date.Value, Parameters!To_date.Value)))))
```

Comment: I can't understand why you divide on 10.40? I want to sum % weekday with expression and when i sum(FIELDS!%weekday) i received 4,8% which is not true....

Comment: I updated my answer and added comment why I divide by 10.40

Comment: Thank you.I found solution.Have a nice day!